# How to bypass the pre-receive hook for a single commit?

Tags: javascript, git, devops, hook, git-push

I want to push the code in java script to the remote repo on git, the repo contains per-recived hook that is scanning the code and I get the error that my code contains private key, after looking into it my code does not contain private key or any secret information. It only contains a word rsa-key that pre-receive hook sees as a threat  and it does no allow me to push my code. Is there any solution how to skip scanning some java script files without using .gitignote, or changing anything in the code because that is not possible right now.

I tried:

```
git push --no-verify
# got the same error 
remote: [WARNING] You are trying to commit a password, token, private key or confidential information which is not allowed in our **** Git
```

Comment: I doubt you can bypass the pre-receive hook from your end since it is like a security measure and therefore designed not to be bypassed. Do you have access to the hook itself, or can you contact whomever does?

Comment: `--no-verify` is for the pre-push hook. You can't bypass a pre-receive hook from your local machine. If the secret detection in the server-side hook is incorrect, you'll need to get the owner of the repo to fix the hook.

Comment: I don't have access to the git hooks, and they are the same for whole organization and also can not be changed only for one repo in the organization

Comment: Does your code rely on having the word 'rsa-key', or can you rename it?

Comment: Regarding, "...they are the same for whole organization and also can not be changed..." But if the hook has a bug in it or is too strict, perhaps updating it would be helpful to the entire organization. (Or by simply presenting your case to the hook owners they may offer a workaround.)

Answer (score 1):

A `pre-receive` hook is set on the server, and cannot be bypassed using only git options from the client side.

---

You may report an issue to the maintainers of the project, and have them update their hook so that your false positive doesn't get rejected anymore,
or perhaps find a workaround in your code to skip the check (e.g: turn `const tag = "rsa-key"` into `const tag = "rsa-"+"key"` or some similar bad hack ...)

You may also ask the maintainers (or, hopefully, read the repo's documentation ...) for a way to give extra instructions to this pre-receive hook -- for example: a special keyword in the commit message (`skip-key-check` ?) or a comment next to the incriminated line in your code (`//pre-receive-secret:skip` ?)